# How do I solve this??

Tags: calculus, optimization

The figure below shows the graphs of $y= \frac 1 2 x^2$ and $y=x+3$. If $\overline{AB}$ is parallel to the $y$-axis, find its greatest length, given that $A$ is a point on the curve between the two points of intersection.

How do I solve this?

[image]

Comment: I suppose $AB$ is parallel to the $y$ axis?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = x+3$ and $g(x) = 1/2 x^2$. You need to maximize $h(x)=f(x) - g(x)$. Then you take $h'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow f'(x)- g'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow 1 = x$ i.e $(1,f(1))$ and $(1,g(1))$ have the greatest distance with your condition.

Comment: +1 Beat me by 8 seconds. I agree that this is the correct way to tackle this problem.

Comment: $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$!

Comment: @vidyarthi what are you talking about?

Comment: $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ and not $\frac{1}{2x^2}$as you accidentally wrote!

Comment: @vidyarthi No. I wrote $1/2x^2$ in which most people clearly read as $\frac{x^2}{2}$. It was even more clear since $g>f$ on this interval in which the max distance occurs. Also, so need for "!", it is highly suggestive.

Answer (score 0):

The greatest length of $AB$ is when $\text{"change in" } y = (x + 3) - (\frac 1 2 x^2)$ takes its largest value.

The line spans the gap between those two functions, so it's length is their difference at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\equiv (x_1,\frac{x_1^{2}}{2}) $ and $B\equiv (x_1,x_1+3)$. Then, the distance to be maximized is $x_1+3-\frac{x_1^2}{2}$, which, on differentiating and equating to zero gives $x_1=1$ whence the greatest length is $\frac{7}{2}$.